# Problem with screen when changing users - nvidia GTX 645

Tags: unity, nvidia

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and 3 users.

When I switch between users sometimes the desktop/unity bar goes fuzzy / not well rendered.

If I minimize all windows it renders well. I have NVIDIA GTX 645 and looking in forums I noticed that some users have problems with this video card under Ubuntu.

What should I do? I'm currently using nvidia driver.

Comment: which version of the driver?

Comment: good question how do I check the version? I just can see nvidia.so

Comment: version is 314.125

Comment: try the 331 / 332 version (whatever else is avaliable)

Answer (score 1):

I was using `nvidia-current` and for some reason this did not give me the latest driver version, so I picked the last one available (359) and it worked well.